# Concatenate object values regarding name of fields in alphabetical order

Tags: java, reflection, java-8, concatenation, java-stream

I'm looking for a method to concatenate object values regarding name of fields in alphabetical order.

Example:

```
public Class Request {
    private String number;
    private String amount;
    private String currency;
}

Request request = new Request();
request.setNumber("tata");
request.setCurrency("toto");
```

With this, my method should return `tototata`.

Method must be generic:

```
public static String concatenate(Object object) { ...}
```

`null` values must not be concatenated.

I already checked out Apache Commons BeanUtils and Java 8 streams, but found nothing nice.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: why would it return "tototata" and not "tatatoto" since 'o' goes after 'a'?

Comment: @nickzoum it's based on the field name.

Comment: Do you want only to handle `String` fields? Or all reference fields? Or all fields including primitive fields? How do you want to handle array/list/collection fields? Do you want fields from superclasses? What if there are multiple fields with the same name in the inheritance hierarchy? (I think you need to think about your requirements a bit; and then have a go yourself)

Comment: in my case all object have only String fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may write this by iterating over all declared fields in the given object.

```
public static String concatenate(Object object) {
    return Arrays.stream(object.getClass().getDeclaredFields())
                 .filter(f -> f.getType() == String.class)
                 .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Field::getName))
                 .map(f -> {
                      try { return (String)f.get(object); }
                      catch (IllegalAccessException e) { return null; }
                  })
                 .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                 .collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

Comment: Why so complicated? Why not doing a type comparison when you want to do a type comparison, i.e. `.filter(f -> f.getType()==String.class)`? And you can use `.sorted(Comparator.comparing(Field::getName))`. And instead of manually creating a `StringBuilder` and using the infamous `forEach`, just use `.collect(Collectors.joining())` as intended for exactly that purpose…

Comment: By the way, this method does not need to declare `throws IllegalAccessException`…

Answer (score 2):

Thanks you Andrew Tobilko, i was doing this (working)

```
    public static String concatenateAlphabetically(Object object) {
        Map<String, String> map = null;
        try {
            map = BeanUtils.describe(object);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // remove class attribute generating from BeanUtils.describe
        map.remove("class");
        map.values().removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
        Map<String, String> treeMap = new TreeMap<String, String>(map);
        return treeMap.values().stream().collect(Collectors.joining());
    }
```

But i don't like to use BeanUtils like this, i prefer your method.

I just add f.setAccessible(true); to access to private fields